# What is meant by : The sum over one period of the values of a periodic complex exponential is zero unless that complex exponential is a constant.

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

What is meant by : The sum over one period of the values of a periodic complex exponential is zero unless that complex exponential is a constant.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{\frac{j2 \pi (p-k)n}{N}}$$
$$ =N; (p-k)=0, \pm N, \pm 2N,...$$
$$ =0; (p-k) \neq N$$

Why is the above summation equal to $0$ if $(p-k)\neq N$

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @saulspatz I have figured out that the above summation is equal to $N $ when $ (p-k)=0, \pm N, \pm 2N,...$

Comment: Are $p$ and $k$ integers?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, they are.

Comment: It's the sum of a geometric progression.

Comment: @saulspatz I have done the steps. Can you please review them?

Comment: The common ratio $r$ is $$e^\frac {j2\pi (p-k)}{N}$$

Comment: So the summation is equal to $$\frac{1-r^N}{1-r}$$

Comment: $$= \frac{1-e^{\frac{j2\pi (p-k) N}{N}}}{1- e^{\frac {j2\pi (p-k)}{N}}} $$

Comment: Which is of the form $\frac {0}{0}$.

Now we have to apply L'Hospitale's Rule. I am not able to understand how we can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with L'Hôpital's rule.  That's for taking limits, and there's no limit here.  Once you get to $$\frac{1-e^{\frac{j2\pi (p-k) N}{N}}}{1- e^{\frac {j2\pi (p-k)}{N}}},$$ note that the numerator is $$1-e^{2\pi j(p-k)}=1-1=0,$$ since $p-k$ is an integer.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, can you please help me with this : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4064364/510439